# Create two or more triggers in a row by executing a query with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Which is the right syntax in order to create two or more triggers in a row by executing a query with **SQL Server**?

I tried the following one:

```
GO
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_MyTable_UpdatedAt
ON dbo.MyTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE dbo.MyTable
    SET UpdatedAt = GETDATE()
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Inserted)
END

GO
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_MyTable_CreatedAt
ON dbo.MyTable
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE dbo.MyTable
    SET CreatedAt = GETDATE()
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Inserted)
END
```

But it returns an error: `Incorrect syntax near 'END'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_MyTable_UpdatedAt
ON dbo.MyTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.MyTable
    SET UpdatedAt = GETDATE()
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Inserted)
END
GO 
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_MyTable_CreatedAt
ON dbo.MyTable
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.MyTable
    SET CreatedAt = GETDATE()
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Inserted)
END

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the matching BEGIN, hence the error being near END. For example;

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_MyTable_UpdatedAt
ON dbo.MyTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.MyTable
    SET UpdatedAt = GETDATE()
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Inserted)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write `'Begin'`

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_MyTable_UpdatedAt
ON dbo.MyTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS
Begin
    UPDATE dbo.MyTable
    SET UpdatedAt = GETDATE()
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Inserted)
END

GO
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_MyTable_CreatedAt
ON dbo.MyTable
AFTER INSERT
AS
Begin
    UPDATE dbo.MyTable
    SET CreatedAt = GETDATE()
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Inserted)
END
GO
```